# Fourier Transform of a function not in Schwartz Space

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I want to calculate the Fourier transform of $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}.$$
It is an exercise in my textbook.

I know that $f(x) \notin \mathcal{S}$, in which $\mathcal{S}$ is the Schwartz Space, and that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) dx$ doesn't converge (even if $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2} \in L^1$ and its Transform is known).

Can I use the formula $$\mathcal{F}(f(x))(w)=\mathcal{F}(xg(x))(w)= i \frac{d \widehat{g}}{dw}(w)?$$ What are the conditions to guarantee that this property is valid?

My doubt is because in the books of Fourier Analysis (and even in questions here in the fórum), the previous result is applied only in $\mathcal{S}$ (that has good properties) and I'm not not sure if only the fact of $g \in \mathcal{L}^1$ is enough to apply it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: $f$ is not in $L^1$, so the usual integral definition doesn't apply. It is however in $L^2$. Do you have the theory of the $L^2$ Fourier transform available?

Comment: In $\lim_{A\to \infty} \int_{-A}^A g(x)e^{-i w x}dx$ you can show that the derivative (wrt $w$) of the limit is the limit of the derivative. A huge generalization of this idea is the Fourier transform in the sense of distributions.

Comment: The theory of $L^2$ Fourier transform isn't available in my textbooks. Just something about $L^1$ or $\mathcal{S}$. If you have a reference to indicated, I would be glad. And I had never studied distributions.

Comment: My advice is to just do the computations without worrying too much about formal justification. It's easier to prove that something you computed is correct, than to do computations carrying a heavy formal burden.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\frac{1}{\pi}\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}e^{-2\pi i xt}\,dx= e^{-2\pi|t|}$.

This can be seen in terms of probability: The characteristic function of the double exponential distribution $\phi(y)=\frac12 e^{-|y|}$ is $g(t)=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$. That later is integrable and so one can use the Fourier inverse theorem.

Recall that for any tempere distribution  $u$,  $\mathcal{F}(u)$ is define as
$\widehat{u}(\phi)=u\big(\mathcal{F}(\phi)\big)\,dx$. In your case, you want to see what the Fourier transform of the distribution $\phi\mapsto \int\frac{x}{1+x^2}\phi(x)\,dx$ is .

Recall that for any $\phi\in\mathcal{S}$, $\mathcal{F}(\phi)\in\mathcal{S}$, and $x\phi(x)\in\mathcal{S}$. You may try to the use

$$\int \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}x\phi(x)\,dx= \langle \mathcal{F}(e^{-2\pi|x|}),x\mathcal{F}(\phi(x))\rangle$$

where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the inner product on $L1$, that is $\langle f,g\rangle =\int f\overline{g}$.

The following identities will come handy: 
$$\langle \mathcal{F}f,\phi\rangle = \langle f,\widetilde{\mathcal{F}\phi}\rangle=\langle f,\mathcal{F}(\widetilde{\phi})\rangle$$
for all $f\in L_1$ nd $\phi\in\mathcal{S}$, where $\widetilde{g}(x)=g(-x)$, and also

\begin{aligned}
D(\mathcal{F}\phi)(t)&=-2\pi i\,\mathcal{F}(x\phi(x))(t)\\
\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}\phi)(x) &= \widetilde{\phi}(x)
\end{aligned}

for all $\phi\in\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Thanks. It is a kind of result I don't have in my undergraduate textbook. I will search for it.

Comment: Formally, you can take derivative w.r.t $t$ in the first identity I produced. That should give you a candidate for the Fourier transform.